# How to place nodes (in TikZ) with different height on two lines, so that the node have the same distance?

Tags: tikz-pgf, signal-processing

This is my modified code from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
                      node distance = 3cm,
                      signal/.style = coordinate,
                      sum/.style = {draw,
                                    circle,
                                    node distance = 2cm
                                   },
                      block/.style = {draw,
                                      rectangle,
                                      minimum height = 2em,
                                      minimum width = 4em
                                     },
                      branch/.style = {sum,
                                       fill = black
                                      }
                     ]
    %placing the blocks
    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[sum, right of = input] (left sum) {};
    \node[block, right of = {left sum}] (controller) {Regler};
    \node[block, right of = controller] (system) {Strecke, $x(t)$};
    %connecting the controller and system to calculate the coordinate u,
    %it needed to place the measurement block
    \draw
      [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u(t)$} (system);
    \node[block, below of = u] (measurement) {Messglied};
    \node[sum, right of = system] (right sum) {};
    \node[signal, above of = {right sum}] (disturbances) {};
    \node[branch, right of = {right sum}] (branch) {};
    %do the same as above (connect system and controller,
    %to be able to place measurement) didn't work here,
    %because the nodes have different height
    \draw
      (right sum) -- (branch);
    \node[sum, below of = branch] (lower sum) {};
    \node[signal, right of = branch] (output) {};
    \node[signal, right of = {lower sum}] (measurement noise) {};
    %connecting the placed nodes
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- node {$w(t)$} (left sum);
    \draw
      [->] (left sum) -- node {$e(t)$} (controller);
    \draw
      [->] (system) -- (right sum);
    \draw
      [->] (disturbances) -- node {$z(t)$} (right sum);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- node {$y(t)$} (output);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement noise) -- node[above] {$m(t)$} (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (lower sum) -- (measurement);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement) -| node[pos = .99] {$-$} (left sum);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the result of my buggy block diagram:

[image: block diagram]

The bugs are:

1. Described in the title.
2. Lines marked with red should have approximately the same length.
3. I failed to manipulate the radius of the circles. Eg. `sum/.style = {draw, circle, radius = 1mm, node distance = 2cm}` does nothing.

In short: How can one solve the above tasks in a bit automate and optimal manner. Any optimizations and also completely different solutions are welcome!

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might solve all your problems, though I'm not entirely certain what you meant in the first point.

To start at the end, with your point 3. There is no `radius` key for circular nodes, use `minimum size` instead, which defines the diameter.

For point 2. When you do `right of=a`, the distance is measured between the centre points of the nodes. When you have nodes of different sizes, the distances between node borders will then vary. But the `<position> of=` keys are considered deprecated anyway, see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386). Instead you should load the `positioning` library with

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

and use `right=of a` and similar. This way, the distance is measured between node borders. (And if you want them measured between node centres, there is the key `on grid` for that, see the manual.)

Finally, the first point. Assuming that you wanted to place the *Messglied* node so that the arrow entering it from the right is horizontal, there are various possibilities.

Below I've moved that node to after the `lower sum` node in the code, and then used

```
\node[block] (measurement) at (u|-lower sum) {Messglied};
```

See [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429) for a description of what `|-` does, if you don't know already.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
                      node distance = 1.2cm,
                      signal/.style = coordinate,
                      sum/.style = {draw,
                                    circle,
                                    minimum size=1.5em % <--- modified
                                   },
                      block/.style = {draw,
                                      rectangle,
                                      minimum height = 2em,
                                      minimum width = 4em
                                     },
                      branch/.style = {sum,
                                       fill = black
                                      }
                     ]
    %placing the blocks
    \node[signal] (input) {};
    \node[sum, right=of input] (left sum) {};
    \node[block, right=of left sum] (controller) {Regler};
    \node[block, right=of controller] (system) {Strecke, $x(t)$};
    %connecting the controller and system to calculate the coordinate u,
    %it needed to place the measurement block
    \draw
      [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u(t)$} (system);
    \node[sum, right=of system] (right sum) {};
    \node[signal, above=of right sum] (disturbances) {};
    \node[branch, right=of right sum] (branch) {};
    %do the same as above (connect system and controller,
    %to be able to place measurement) didn't work here,
    %because the nodes have different height
    \draw
      (right sum) -- (branch);
    \node[sum, below=of branch] (lower sum) {};
    \node[signal, right=of branch] (output) {};
    \node[signal, right=of lower sum] (measurement noise) {};
    % place measurement node
    \node[block] (measurement) at (u|-lower sum) {Messglied}; % <-- modified
    %connecting the placed nodes
    \draw
      [->] (input) -- node {$w(t)$} (left sum);
    \draw
      [->] (left sum) -- node {$e(t)$} (controller);
    \draw
      [->] (system) -- (right sum);
    \draw
      [->] (disturbances) -- node {$z(t)$} (right sum);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- node {$y(t)$} (output);
    \draw
      [->] (branch) -- (lower sum);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement noise) -- node[above] {$m(t)$} (lower sum);
    \draw
      [,->] (lower sum) -- (measurement);
    \draw
      [->] (measurement) -| node[pos = .99] {$-$} (left sum);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Sorry for the long delay and my incorrect english. Thank you for your answer! It looks great! For my needs the *sum nodes* should be smaller (diameter smaller than the height) than the *block nodes*. If I do so (eg.`sum/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 1pt}`), than the connection between *lower sum* and *measurement* is sloped as I had before, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZXZV.png. I tried to solve it like you do with `\node[block, below = of left sum.south -| u] (measurement) {Messglied}` eg. `\node[sum, right = of measurement -| branch] (lower sum) {};`.

Comment: Than the connection between *measurement* is horizontal, but the connection between *branch* and *lower sum* is than sloped, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VelK.png. Also the *branch nodes* should be smaller than the sum nodes. The `minimum size=` command don't helps in this case. Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 I think I realized right after posting the answer that I used a stupid way of solving that bit. Anyways, answer updated.

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Thank you for your comment! Now it works! Only last task is to do: The *branch nodes* should be smaller than the *sum nodes* (the diameter). For every value of the `minimum size=` command the *sum* and *branch nodes* have the same diameter. Is there a way, to leave the *sum nodes* like it is now and make the *branch nodes* smaller? Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 Sorry, missed that part. Of course, just add a smaller `minimum size` in the `branch` style, after `sum`. E.g .`branch/.style={sum,minimum size=1em,fill=black}`.

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Thank you for your comment! I solved it with `sum/.style = {draw, circle, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 2mm}` and `branch/.style = {sum, minimum size = 1mm, fill = black}`. I took it from @Zarko's answer. Thank you both for your effort! My next [task](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403083/how-one-can-automatically-draw-a-line-in-a-rectangle).

Answer (score 1):

you have more issues in your code:

- you use obsolete syntax for node positioning. recently require `positioning` library and nodes are relativela positioned for example as `\node[sum, right = of in] (sum-in) {}`
- in sum style definition you determine `node distance` again, but with different amount as is for others scheme elemewnts
- in relative positioning you should consider node height (couse that lower sum is not aligned.

correcting this, i obtain:

[image]

**edit:** your code can by simplified with employing of the following `tikz` libraries: `calc`,`chains` and `positioning`. for beautiful arrows i suggest to use `arrows.meta` library.

- scheme block are positioned in chain
- for block names is used chain name (`A`, so the first block is `A-1`)
- for shorter code for connection lines is added code, which enable draw edges without repeating block names. for example:

standard

```
\path   (in)    edge ["$w(t)$"] (A-1)
        (A-1)   edge ["$e(t)$"] (A-2)
...
```

proposed solution enable

```
\path   (in)    edge ["$w(t)$"] (A-1)
        (A-1)   edge ["$e(t)$"] (A-2)
...
```

- for edge labels is used `quotes` library

complete *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, chains, 
                positioning, 
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 1cm and 1.5cm,
  start chain = A going right,
   sum/.style = {circle,
                 draw,
                 inner sep=0mm, minimum size=4mm,
                 node contents={}
                 },
 block/.style = {rectangle, 
                 draw,    
                 minimum height = 2em,
                 minimum width = 4em,
                 inner sep=2mm, outer sep =0mm
                 },
branch/.style = {circle,
                 inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm,
                 fill = black,
                 node contents={}
                 },
every edge/.append code = {%
\global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable
\pgfkeysalso{append after command={(\currenttarget)}}% automatically repeat it
                           },
every edge/.append style = {-Straight Barb},
                     ]
%placing the blocks
    \coordinate (in);
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain=A}]
\node [sum, right=of in];           % A-1
\node [block]   {Regler};
\node [block]   {Strecke, $x(t)$};
\node [sum];
\node [branch];                     % A-5
    \end{scope};
\coordinate [right=of A-5]  (out);
\node (A-6) [block, below = of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$]   {Messglied};
    \coordinate[above = of A-4]   (z);
\node (A-7) [sum, at = {(A-6 -| A-5)}];
    \coordinate[right=of A-7]   (m);
% conections
\path   (in)    edge ["$w(t)$"] (A-1)
                edge ["$e(t)$"] (A-2)
                edge ["$u(t)$"] (A-3)
                edge            (A-4)
                edge            (A-5)
                edge ["$y(t)$"] (out)
        (z)     edge ["$z(t)$"] (A-4)
        (A-5)   edge            (A-7)
        (m)     edge ["$m(t)$" ']   (A-7)
                edge            (A-6);
\draw[-Straight Barb]    
        (A-6) -| (A-1) node[below left] {$-$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Zarko! Sorry for the long delay. Your variant is a bit tricky for me. Anyway, thank you for your effort!

Comment: what is tricky? code is simple, clear and easy to understand, well, at least for me :-) . if you have problems with undertaking some parts, please ask, i will try to explain in more details

Comment: Hello @Zarko! Thank you for your comment! I understand the variant of Torbjørn T. immediately, so I choose this one. For your variant I have to invest more time. I hope you understand me correctly. I haven't enough time for everything, so I should to choose, like every other person. And thank you for your effort!